# Faster way to check what entities are intersecting?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have array of entities (`Manager.Scene.Entities`) that technically are circles. 
And I have a method, that returns array of entities that intersects with current entity:

```
var Intersected = Manager.Scene.Entities.filter(function (another) {
        //check cases that not initiate intersection to prevent extra calculations
        if (self.radius < another.radius 
             || another.id == self.id 
             || self.className == another.className)
            return false;

        //check circles intersections
        var dx = self.x - another.x;
        var dy = self.y - another.y;
        dx = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        dy = self.radius + another.radius;

        return dx < dy * dy;
    });
```

I profiled it and noticed that this method takes 28% of execution time (look at picture).
[image: Profile results]

Is it possible to optimize it somehow?

---

**PS.** I modified intersection checking, now it founds nearby entities, and than checks intersections. It takes 21% of ex. time, instead of 28%.

```
    var Nearest = Manager.Scene.Entities.filter(function (another) {
        return self.x * 2 > another.x || self.x / 2 < another.x || self.y * 2 > another.y || self.y / 2 < another.y;
    });

    var Intersected = Nearest.filter(function (another) {
        if (self.radius < another.radius || another.id == self.id || self.className == another.className)
            return false;

        var dx = self.x - another.x;
        var dy = self.y - another.y;
        dx = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        dy = self.radius + another.radius;

        return dx < dy * dy;
    });
```

Comment: I assume you compute intersections on all entities: use a [spatial partitioning strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) to avoid `O(n^2)` behaviour

Comment: @BeyelerStudios that's interesting to hear. I don't do neither gamedev nor graphics/physics, and I extrapolated that for complex shapes it's more beneficial.

Comment: @zerkms it's cheaper to *compute* the bounding box (min,max) of something than the (exact) [bounding sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere), but the intersection test of bounding spheres is just a comparison of distances while bounding box involves multiple comparisons

Comment: why self.radius < another.radius == false?

Comment: not sure if I've understood. radius is just the distance from the center, how do you know one circle does not intercept the other just comparing their radiuses?

Comment: @leo because smaller entity cant interact with larger

Comment: well, I think you should add more conditions to detect when it's NOT going to collide. Most probably the multiplication is the expensive part of this method

Answer (score 0):

You could win a great deal of time with only a few efforts by pre-computing the couples that might intersect. Keep such an array up to date every time you add/remove an entity, and you can avoid the first test.
Provided your id is in deed an id, the code could look like :

```
var colliders [];
var possibleCollisions = [];

function addCollider(newCollider) {
   if (colliders.indexOf(newCollider)>=0) throw('collider already added');
   colliders.forEach(function(c) {
        if ((c.radius>newCollider.radius) && (c.class!=newCollider.class)) 
           possibleCollision.push([  c, 
                                     newCollider, 
                          Math.pow(c.radius + newCollider.radius,2) ]);
   });
   colliders.push(newCollider);
}

function removeColliders(deadCollider) {
   var deadColliderIndex = colliders.indexOf(deadCollider);
   if (deadColliderIndex==-1) throw('collider already removed');
   possibleCollision = possibleCollision.filter(
       function(pc) { return ((pc[0]!=deadCollider)&&(pc[1]!=deadCollider));
   });
   colliders.splice(deadColliderIndex, 1);
}
```

Now to test for all collisions, iterate inside possibleCollisions.

Notice that you can store the sum of radius (or its square) to further optimize things.

```
 function detectCollision(possibleCollision) {
    var a = possibleCollision[0], b = possibleCollision[1],
          radiusSumSq = possibleCollision[3];
    var dx = a.x - b.x;
    var dy = a.y - b.y;
    return dx*dx + dy*dy <= radiusSumSq;
 }
```

Comment: If I understood you right, I must update colliders data every time when entity added, removed or entity's position changed?

Comment: When added/remove, yes you should update collider list, and possible collision list, but not when they move - that does not change the possibilities of collision - .